# How to make sure only one of the variables is set to true?

Tags: dart

```dart
class Foo {
  final bool a;
  final bool b;
  final bool c;
  final bool d;

  Foo({
    this.a = false,
    this.b = false,
    this.c = false,
    this.d = false,
  }) : assert(a ^ b ^ c ^ d, 'Only one of them can be true.');
}
```

I want to make sure that only one of the properties `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` can be `true`. I tried `a ^ b ^ c ^ d` but it didn't work for this case.

**Note:** I'm not looking for doing it the lengthy way i.e. `(a && !b && !c && !d) || (!a && b && !c && !d) ...`

Comment: maybe `!!a + !!b + !!c + !!d == 1`... lol. but why not just use an `enum` instead of a bunch of `bool`s? then it can only have one value at any time, by definition, so you don't need to worry about preserving that invariant.

Comment: @underscore_d `!!a` is the same as `a`.  It would not transform a `bool` to an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general technique would be to put your booleans into a `List` and then count the number of `true` elements.  This also would allow you to check whether exactly a certain number are true, at least a certain number are true, or at most a certain number are true.

Here are a couple ways to implement that:

```dart
extension CountExtension<T> on Iterable<T> {
 /// Returns a count of the elements in `this` that are equal to [value].
 int countOf(T value) => fold<int>(0, ((sum, e) => sum + ((e == value) ? 1 : 0)));
}

T identity<T>(T object) => object;

void main() {
  var booleans = [true, false, true, false];
  print(booleans.countOf(true)); // Prints: 2
  print(booleans.where(identity).length); // Prints: 2
}
```

and applied to your example:

```dart
class Foo {
  final bool a;
  final bool b;
  final bool c;
  final bool d;

  Foo({
    this.a = false,
    this.b = false,
    this.c = false,
    this.d = false,
  }) {
    assert([a, b, c, d].countOf(true) == 1, 'Exactly one must be true');

    // Or alternatively:

    assert(
      [a, b, c, d].where(identity).length == 1,
      'Exactly one must be true',
    );
  }
}
```

(I expect something equivalent to `countOf` exists in a common package somewhere already, but I can't seem to find one at the moment.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want it in a constructor `assert`, I'll assume you also want a *constant* expression (because otherwise `[a, b, c, d].where((x)=>x).length == 1` will do, as @jamesdlin showed).

The shortest I can come up with using only the base Boolean operators is

```dart
  assert((a || b || c || d) && 
         !(a && b || a && c || a && d || b && c || b && d || c && d))
```

Not that great, quadratic in the number of variables.

Using `?`/`:` can make it smaller:

```dart
  assert(a ? !(b || c || d) : b ? !(c || d) : c ^ d)
```

Also quadratic, just with a (significantly!) smaller constant factor.

If you look at a necessary [*binary decision diagram*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) (like a binary decision tree, only it's a DAG) for the Boolean function, it's actually linear, so that suggests that you can make a linear expression with only Boolean operators, but it does so by sharing subtrees, which would mean that you need either more complicated control flow or local variables.
With a `let` constructor, you could do:

```dart
let cd1 = c ^ d, 
    ncd = !c && !d, 
    bcd1 = b ? ncd : cd1, 
    nbcd = !b && ncd
in a ? nbcd : bcd1
```

which scales to a linear expression in an arbitrary number of variables
(because of the sharing of `ncd` here, which becomes even more sharing with more variables).
It's really the same as the `?`/`:` version above with identical sub-expressions being shared.
Sadly, Dart doesn't have a `let` construct that you can use in an `assert`, so that's just theoretical fun.

So, I too would go with arithmetic operations, because you *are* counting:

```dart
 assert((a ? 1 : 0) + (b ? 1 : 0) + (c ? 1 : 0) + (d ? 1 : 0) == 1)
```

That expression is simple, linear, and valid in a `const` constructor `assert`.